# C#, compare two different type of lists

Tags: c#, list, object, compare

I have list of objects and I have list of strings.

```
List<String> states = new List<String>();
states.add("wisconsin");
states.add("Florida");
states.add("new york");

List<Foo> foo = new List<Foo>();
foo.add(new Foo(2000, name1, "wisconsin"));
foo.add(new Foo(1000, name2, "california"));
foo.add(new Foo(300, name3, "Florida"));
```

An object have three properties:
int age, string name and string state.

and I have added these objects to the list. Second list consists of string of "states".

How I can compare these two lists? What is best way to do it?
I want to know if one of objects have same "state", which other list consist.
Please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should add two more things to your question: first, what do you mean by "compare"? Since you have objects of different types, the comparison is clearly *not* apples to apples. Second, you should post some code that shows your own attempt at solving this problem. Good luck!

Comment: What kind of comparison you want to do? You want to remove stuff from the lists or do you want to know if a certain condition is fulfilled?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
List<Person> people = ...;
List<string> states = ...;

var peopleWithKnownStates = people.Where(p => states.Contains(p.State));
```

Or just to find if *any* of the people have known states:

```
var anyPersonHasKnownState = people.Any(p => states.Contains(p.State));
```

Both of these use LINQ - if you haven't come across it before, you should definitely look into it. It's wonderfully useful.

You might want to change your `states` to a `HashSet<string>` so that the `Contains` operation is quicker though.