# Compare items of two different type of lists c#

Tags: c#

I want to compare two different lists with one property in common (Name). I have tried things like the .Contains() method, but that does not work because I am dealing with lists of two different objects. I have tried the solutions in questions like:

[C# Compare Two Lists of Different Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550263/c-sharp-compare-two-lists-of-different-objects)

[C#, compare two different type of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120386/c-compare-two-different-type-of-lists)

[compare different type of list in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168758/compare-different-type-of-list-in-c-sharp)

But these solutions do not work because my lists expect a Property or Animal object and not a "string", this is where I get stuck.

I have two classes:

```
 public class Animal
    {
        public string Name = string.Empty;
        public string XChromosome = string.Empty;
        public string YChromosome = string.Empty;
    }

public class Properties
{
    public string Name = string.Empty;
    public string Prop1 = string.Empty;
    public string Prop2 = string.Empty;
}
```

The two lists look like this:

```
List<Animal> = "name", "xposition", "yposition"
               "name1", "xposition1", "yposition1" etc..

List<Properties> = "name", "prop1","prop2"
                   "name1", "prop3", "prop4" etc..
```

What I would like to do do is, compare these two lists and if the "Name" matches I would like to get the content of both lists belonging to this name. I also tried using a HashSet or a Dictionary, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: create an interface which both can implement, which contains only the name property. Then have a function which accepts instances of that Interface and compares them using only the Name property.

Comment: Are they supposed to be handled in your code base as common entity? To me, based on the name, animal doesn't have anything to do with properties, so it seems very unlikely that there is a need to treat them in the same way. I think @ADyson statement might be to simple as to just join create a shared interface

Comment: In the code I need to compare the properties with the chromosomes, the only thing that links them is the name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) two lists on `Name` property and get matches as anonymous object:

```
from a in animals
join p in properties on a.Name equals p.Name
select new {
   a.Name,
   a.XChromosome,
   a.YChromosome,
   p.Prop1,
   p.Prop2
}
```

You can try it yourself in [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bxbu3w).

---

NOTE: If you want to get animal info no matter if there is match in properties, or you can have more than one match for given animal, then you need to use [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297(v=vs.110).aspx) ([check this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ydzv5) for details):

```
  from a in animals
  join p in properties on a.Name equals p.Name into g
  from p in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new {
     a.Name,
     a.XChromosome,
     a.YChromosome,
     Prop1 = p?.Prop1,
     Prop2 = p?.Prop2
  }
```

That wil return each pair of animal - property joined by name. If no matching property found, then Prop1 and Prop2 will have null values by default (though you can provide any default value you want).

Comment: If I implement this my compiler complains about: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. EDIT: I found the solution, my mistake

Comment: @E.O. I have added runnable code which you can play with. Check it and see what is missing in your code. BTW I suggest you to use properties instead of fields in your classes

Comment: Thanks for your runnable code ! This seemed to be the solution to my problem

Answer (score 1):

Sergey Berezovsky's solution is good, deserves all the upvotes and to be the accepted answer, however, I would like to add an alternative as well. You could create a `class` called `Named`, like this:

```
class Named {
    public string Name = string.Empty;
}
```

and inherit your `class`es from it, like this:

```
 public class Animal : Named
    {
        public string XChromosome = string.Empty;
        public string YChromosome = string.Empty;
    }

public class Properties : Named
{
    public string Prop1 = string.Empty;
    public string Prop2 = string.Empty;
}
```

This will enable you to use `List<Named>` as type which will allow you to do your task easily either with LINQ or with a cycle. The benefit of this approach is that you will not duplicate the same member in both `class`es and if you are going to have more cases when you need to do something like this or you are going to have more similar members and/or methods, then you will not duplicate your code.